# Howto combine TouchID <=> React Native <=> Amazon Cognito

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, touch-id

has somebody, who read this, experience with authentication using your thumb, 
 **TouchID**, in a **React Native** App, which uses **Amazon Cognito** as authentication service?

I'm a newbie using React Native, and a real beginner using Cognito. Maybe someone knows a tutorial for this?

Thx :-)

Comment: Which branch of Cognito are you trying to use?

Comment: Currently none. Means: I can choose. I asked, before trying anything and wasting my time trying to invent the wheel again.

Comment: I don't know of a tutorial that does all of this. You could use either Cognito User Pools' custom auth *or* Cognito Federated Identities developer authenticated identities. What might help to decide between is what else your app needs to do. If it needs to access other AWS resources, I'd recommend federated identities.

Comment: You will need to use a third party library for Touch ID / Fingerprint Authentication, there's a few to choose from on https://www.npmjs.com/. What you'll want to do is securely store credentials on the device (in the keychain for iOS), and when the user authenticates using Touch ID, use the stored credentials to authenticate against cognito.

Comment: Thank you. My boss paused this so I couldn't do any more research on that.

Answer (score 0):

A preview project which is using REACT NATIVE - COGNITO

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-react-native/tree/master/Core/example

Touch ID is not involved in this example.